# Wormhole-like tunnels used to look back in time

Tags: story-identification

I read a book a while ago in which a device is invented which opens up "tunnels" back through time. These tunnels cannot be traveled through, but can be used to view what happened in the past. I believe it starts out narrating the invention of the device, then skips ahead to after it is widely in use. There is another device created, a cloak of sorts,  which hides the user from the view of someone using the tunnel device. Does this ring a bell with anyone?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99632/scifi-book-where-scientists-learn-to-peek-through-time-possibly-controlled-mini (more comprehensive answer)

Comment: Even better one [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82776/looking-for-book-about-device-that-allowed-people-to-look-back-in-time?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's almost certainly [The Light of Other Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days).

Arthur C. Clarke and Stephen Baxter were co-authors.

Comment: Ah, that sounds right! I love books that address the social implications of scifi technology.