# Looking for a book about small wormholes used for viewing other places/times

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title of a book where somebody created the ability to make small wormholes. These wormholes were so small, they wouldn't be seen by the naked eye. They were one directional, meaning light could only travel through in one direction, allowing only viewing, like a telescope, through the wormhole.

Later in the book it was discovered that these wormholes could also connect to times in the past (not future) revealing any and all secrets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly [The Light of Other Days](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/823062.The_Light_of_Other_Days), by Stephen Baxter and Arthur C. Clarke.  From the synopsis:

> When a brilliant, driven industrialist harnesses the cutting edge of quantum physics to enable people everywhere, at trivial cost, to see one another at all times: around every corner, through every wall, into everyone's most private, hidden, and even intimate moments. It amounts to the sudden and complete abolition of human privacy--forever.

## Update

Although I didn't take the time to do a search before answering, this question has been asked multiple times, and a good excerpt from the book may be found [in this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/99634/28471).

Comment: [Ahem](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/looking-for-a-book-about-small-wormholes-used-for-viewing-other-places-times#comment414658_158041)

Comment: Ack. Nor did I see your reply in the comments prior to posting, @Valorum.

Comment: No worries. Now that OP has accepted it, we can close it as a dupe