# Book about an industrialist in a world where technology is used to remote view in time and space

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

A book published in the late '90s or 2000s, I think. The world was built around a technology that exploits relativistic effects to remote view in time and space. The narrator is an industrialist who was at the center of the technology.

The children of the protagonist/narrator were very concerned about the privacy implications of the technology. One did all private acts - drug use, sexual activity etc - in public since there was no privacy, and another did everything in complete darkness since to illuminate such conditions revealed the "watchers".

Help me find this book, please.

Comment: My first thought is "The light of other days" by Clarke and Baxter

Comment: @DannyMcG.  I agree.  I would suggest you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm suggesting *The Light of Other Days* by Arthur C. Clarke and Stephen Baxter

[From the Wikipedia entry:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days)

> Wormhole technology has advanced to the point where information can be passed instantaneously between points in the spacetime continuum. The wormhole technology is first used to send digital information via gamma rays, then developed further to transmit light waves. The media corporation that develops this advance can spy on anyone, anywhere it chooses. A logical development from the laws of space-time allows light waves to be detected from the past. This enhances the wormhole technology into a "time viewer" where anyone opening a wormhole can view people and events from any point throughout time and space.

When the technology is released to the general public, it effectively destroys all secrecy and privacy.

Possibly the same book here
[SciFi book where scientists learn to peek through time (possibly controlled miniature wormhole?). Computer screens were carried like a handkerchief](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99632/scifi-book-where-scientists-learn-to-peek-through-time-possibly-controlled-mini)

Comment: Thanks for your help Light of Other Days is the novel I was thinking of, the story is more intense than I remembered it.

Comment: @Openmindedhick - if this is the story you were looking for please mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by hitting the check mark below the voting buttons, as per the [tour].